# how to merge 2 lists of strings with the and operator

Tags: python, list, loops

I am trying to merge 2 lists using the AND operator as follows:

```
testlist1 = inverted_index['amsterdam']
testlist2 = inverted_index['utrecht']
merged_testlist = []
for i in testlist1:
    for index in testlist2:
        if i in testlist1 and i in testlist2 and i not in merged_testlist:
            merged_testlist.append(i)
            
            
            
print(merged_testlist)
```

both lists are made of of a list of ints, testlist1 looks as follows:
`[9756244, 16916567, 21859206, 25186285, 26784347, 29218587, 29406610, 33741990]`

the result I get from my code is an empty list. How do I iterate over both lists, see which indices are in both lists using the AND operator, and append them to my empty merge_testlist?

Comment: First off, `i in testlist1` is always true. If you want to prevent duplicates, use a set, then you can remove `i not in merged_testlist`... So, now explain what `i in testlist2` is supposed to test?

Comment: Iterate over one list (only). For each item in that list see if it's in the 2nd list. If it is, add it to your result list. Or use `list(set(a) & set(b))` for the (list) intersection of lists a and b.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `set` and `intersection` to do it.

```
testlist1 = inverted_index['amsterdam']
testlist2 = inverted_index['utrecht']
merged_testlist = list(set(testlist1).intersection(set(testlist2))
print(merged_testlist)
```